# mirroring and Vps connectivity issue

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two servers. One is dedicated and other is a VPS. I want mirror between both of them so we can utilize our VPS for our client connectivity.

Comment: You need to give more information. What software/versions are you running on each server? What have you tried? Why didn't your attempts work? Are there any error messages?

Comment: At certain point of time We have this message coming on our Server and crashes our Applications 
In this reference I will tell you what is the error which crashes our applications 
"there-is-insufficient-system-memory-in-resource-pool-internal-to-run-this-query"
We are using Sql Server 2008 R2 
on Windows 64 Bit Server